# Is there any use/benefit with using reduceRight() in javascript other than reducing an array value to single value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I came across reduceRight() method in javascript but seems similar to reduce() function of reducing array.So there is no real usage of these two only either one be there

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753527/when-to-use-reduce-and-reduceright see this information for clarity.

Comment: https://1loc.dev/#compose-functions and also this example

Comment: Does this answer your question? [when to use reduce and reduceRight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20753527/when-to-use-reduce-and-reduceright)